# Angular ngx-markdown destroying markdown and converting to plain text

Tags: angular, angularjs, markdown

so I've been having an issue in my Angular project, I am aiming to use markdown to render content on a web page and so I decided to give ngx-markdown a try. Now I believe I have everything imported correctly, directives correctly used, etc...

My issue is whenever I use `<markdown src="'assets/md/data.md'"></markdown>`, the md file certainly displays on the page but it's like all the markdown is deleted, leaving an unformatted text. [Output of md file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4H2M.png). So that's like all bullet points, header sizing, code formatting, etc... being mysteriously deleted, but **bold markdown** seems to work.

I am using TailwindCSS for style, however I have tried using the `<markdown>` selector without any formatting on an individual page, I've tried using `[data]=""`, I've scoured documentation and the internet examples, I'm pretty sure my dependencies are sufficient in my `packages.json` file.

Now since I have installed ngx-markdown, marked, prismjs, mermaid, clipboard, katex, and emoji-toolkit, I have been getting this error but I doubt it contributes to my problem [Warning output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwQKS.png)

Here's my relevant `package.json` information

```
"clipboard": "^2.0.11",
"emoji-toolkit": "^8.0.0",
"katex": "^0.16.0",
"marked": "^9.1.6",
"mermaid": "^10.8.0",
"ngx-markdown": "^17.1.1",
"prismjs": "^1.29.0",
```

My app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { Scroll2TopComponent } from './shared/scroll2-top/scroll2-top.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

//External Modules
import { MarkdownModule, provideMarkdown } from 'ngx-markdown';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    Scroll2TopComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MarkdownModule.forRoot({
      loader: HttpClient,
      sanitize: SecurityContext.NONE,
      
    }),
    MarkdownModule.forChild()
  ],
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideMarkdown({ loader: HttpClient })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally just my html on my "Home" page

```
<section>
    <div>
        <div>
            <markdown [src]="'assets/md/2024-02-27.md'"></markdown>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Edit: Figured I should actually include the md file for reproducibility:

````
---

### Syntax highlight
\`\`\`typescript
const language = 'typescript';
\`\`\`

### Lists
1. Ordered list
2. Another bullet point
   - Unordered list
   - Another unordered bullet

### Blockquote
> Blockquote to the max```
````

Answer (score 0):

So, conveniently I am able to answer my own question.

Apparently using ngx-markdown in conjunction with Tailwind CSS creates this problem in React users as well. The solution is as simple as installing the Tailwind Typography plugin and then using the "prose" type in your classes.

Install tailwind typography:
`npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography`

Include the `@tailwindcss/typography` in your `tailwind.config.js` in the plugins array:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography')
  ],
}
```

The tailwind documentation for this can also be found here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#typography

Then after you've done all that, it's as simple as this (I recommend using max-w-full):

```
<div class="prose max-w-full">
    <markdown [src]="'assets/md/data.md'"></markdown>
</div>
```

I hope this helps with anyone else on the internet experiencing this issue, learning a framework is a learning curve :)